# Change opacity of an element during drag with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, draggable, opacity

**Hi there,**

I'm currently working on a slider made with RoyalSlider. In this slider I've got arrows left and right. So, my code, to made it simple, is something like that :

```
<div class="royalslider">
    <div class="slide">Slide Content</div>
    <div class="slide">Slide Content</div>
    <div class="slide">Slide Content</div>
    <div class="arrowleft"></div>
    <div class="arrowright"></div>
</div>
```

The slides are draggable by the mouse, or you can click arrow to go next or previous...

with the API of royalSlider, I can manage, event like this :

```
slider.ev.on('rsDragStart', function(event) {
    // mouse/touch drag start
});

slider.ev.on('rsDragRelease', function() {
    // mouse/touch drag end
});
```

**My question is :**

I want to animate the opacity of my arrow from 1 (initial state) to 0 when i'm dragging my slides, I mean in relation to the slide position.

**eg :**

I start dragging my slide, the opacity begin to fadeOut, I stop  dragging but don't release my slide, the opacity stop fading, I move the other side, opacity fadeIn....

Is it possible with jquery to do something like this ??

Hope I'm clear :-/

**Many thanks**

PS: Sorry for my frenglish :)

Comment: You need either a JSFiddle of the existing code, or an example of what you have attempted to do with the opacity. It may be as simple as calling `stop` before each animate.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is about how to handle opacity of the element in jquery, yes you can do it very elegantly.
Here is the API link, http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/fading/
And if you want to play with Fiddle, here it is, http://jsfiddle.net/80kqetf4/

Now coming back to your case, something like below would help,

```
    slider.ev.on('rsDragStart', function(event) {
        // mouse/touch drag start
        var visibility = <calculate visibility based on slider position>; // 0-min & 1-max
        $('selector').fadeTo(1000, visibility);
    });

   slider.ev.on('rsDragRelease', function() {
        // mouse/touch drag end
        var visibility = <calculate visibility based on slider position>; // 0-min & 1-max
        $('selector').fadeTo(1000, visibility);
   });
```

Of course you could optimize this code further..